# Disable vibrating when a music player notification appears

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-vibration

How can i disable vibrating when notification appeared?

I used `startForground(int, int);` in `PlayerService` class.

- I update my notification on play and pause state, while notification updates states it starts to vibrating and i want to disable it forever.

Any solutions?

NOTE: I tried many ways but it starts vibrating again.

`builder.setDefault(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);`

`builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L})`

`uilder.setVibrate(new long[]{01, 01})`

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel;
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    String title = playlist().get(play_song_id).get(1);
    String content = getSongArtists();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        channel = new NotificationChannel("lawanmusic", "lawanmusic", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setLightColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        channel.enableVibration(false);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 01, 01 });
        channel.enableVibration(false);
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | -Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE).setVibrate(new long[]{ 0L });
    builder.setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2).setCancelButtonIntent(null).setMediaSession(new MediaSessionCompat(this, "media").getSessionToken()).setShowActionsInCompactView());
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(content);
    @DrawableRes int icon = R.drawable.play_icon_notification;
    builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
    builder.setLargeIcon(getSongCover());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class).putExtra("player", true), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    final PendingIntent prev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(this, PlayerReceiver.class).setAction(PREV_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_prev, "Prev", prev);
    final PendingIntent pause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(this, PlayerReceiver.class).setAction(PAUSE_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_pause, "Pause", pause);
    final PendingIntent next = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(this, PlayerReceiver.class).setAction(NEXT_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_next, "Next", next);
    final PendingIntent stop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(this, PlayerReceiver.class).setAction(STOP_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_stop, "Player Off", stop);
    builder.setShowWhen(false);
    builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | -Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.vibrate = null;
    notification = builder.build();
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: What are the many ways that you have tried?

Comment: first thanks to reply, and question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be creating the NotificationChannel with IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT which the documentation says:

> Default notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise, but
>   does not visually intrude.

You probably want IMPORTANCE_LOW:

> Low notification importance: shows everywhere, but is not intrusive.

Or IMPORTANCE_MIN:

> No sound and does not appear in the status bar

But I can't be sure because I haven't seen all your code surrounding this service

[Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: But i seen many players before works fine >> like Retro Music app

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that those that you've seen before were built and/or targeted SDK's before Android 8.0, which was when Android implemented and enforced the notification channels. Which SDK are you targeting?

Comment: I use SDK 28 in my builde.gradle.

Comment: I think that aligns with Android 9.0, so the notifications channels would apply...